# MySQL - ODER BY vs. PHP sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I'm developing a big CRM system and the buyer wants it really well optimized. It has some really huge tables for displaying clients, products etc that need to be sorted and filtered in different ways. I was wondering which would be faster and use less memory: using ORDER BY in MySQL queries or sorting the results in arrays in PHP? There are some sorting algorithms I can think of that would work really good for my data, but maybe doing it MySQL-side would be faster anyway (one line of code for both getting data and sorting instead of processing it further)? Also, does MySQL use one sorting algorithm (if yes, which one?) or does it depend on column's datatype?

Comment: Why don't you simply test out which is best?

Comment: ^This.  :P  Performance tuning is a situational thing.  If it really matters, don't take the word of a bunch of strangers on the internet -- test it out for yourself, on your hardware, with your data.  That's the only way you're going to *know* what's best.

Comment: Because I'm at the point of writing the specs. Client wants it really detailed and I'm just doing some research. Also he didn't give me access to the actual data yet, but I know the general DB structure so I guess I could test it out a bit on some example data.

Comment: As stated it is impossible to say because different circumstances can have wildly different effects. It really depends on the final data, is copying a huge amout of data, sending/reading/processing it into php -- and then sorting faster? in most cases it really should be faster on db, but again there are always exceptions.

Comment: Sounds like this is your first system or something. Typically, with a well designed system, your sorting will be done by the database system. Any other optimization is done on a case by case basis after exhausting database solutions and only after proven too slow, and your options are limited, and most likely it won't involve sorting in code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd always go for mysql sorting over PHP sorting as it's always turned out way more efficient for large data sets in my experience. Just make sure you have indexed the sort and condition columns relevant in your query, and use mysql EXPLAIN on your queries to check that your not triggering a filesort operation or use of temporary tables. If you can manage that, you'll probably find mysql ordering to be faster in the majority of cases.